# Finding "? and number behind it"

Tags: powershell, numbers, symbols

I've this little script

```
Select-String -Path XXX\*.VML, XXX\*.STA -pattern "\?[a-z]", "\?[\,, \., \ , \!, \?, \*, \+, \-, \(, \)]", "\?_"
```

And I need to add pattern to look up for "?1" , "?2", etc.. from 0 - 9, can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\d` is for "digit", so:

```
Select-String ... -Pattern '\?\d(?!>\d)'
```

The negative lookahead at the end (`(?!>\d)`) will ensure it's not followed by another digit, so it'll match `?1` and `?2` but not `?12`